# Linkedin API `/organizationalEntityAcls` returns "message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-roleAssignee /organizationalEntityAcls"

Tags: linkedin-api

I am working on Linkedin API Integration V2 & trying to get all companies/organization of an authenticated account but i got this error
`{ StatusCodeError: 403 - {"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-roleAssignee /organizationalEntityAcls","status":403}`

Although my app has permission [rw_organization_admin]

Comment: Are you requesting the rw_organization_admin permission scope within your OAuth request? Can you share your full API request to the organizationalEntityAcls API?

Comment: Yes i sent it `/v2/authorization?client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri=https://localhost/&response_type=code&scope=r_emailaddress,r_ads,w_organization_social,rw_ads,r_basicprofile,r_liteprofile,r_ads_reporting,r_organization_social,rw_organization_admin,w_member_social`

Comment: @ChristopherOu my request
 `{ uri: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&projection=(elements*(*,roleAssignee~(localizedFirstName, localizedLastName), organizationalTarget~(localizedName)))',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer- ACCESS_TOKEN },
}`

Comment: Try submitting a ticket to linkedin.zendesk.com including all of this information along with your client id.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristopherOu, adding the `rw_organization_admin` scope was what we needed to do.

Comment: rw_organization_admin  worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to add the `rw_organization_admin` scope, and also trough the LinkedIn Developer portal adding to your app the product: "Marketing Developer Platform", that is the one containing the endpoint: `/v2/organizationAcls`. To add the "Marketing Developer Platform" product, LinkedIn will ask you to compile a form, and than they will accept or refuse your request.

Comment: I am still getting this error, even I have rw_organization_admin scope and permission. What can I miss?

Comment: I found I needed the role=ADMINISTRATOR qs argument also for the /v2/organizationAcls endpoint.